# The action 'update' could not be found for Admin::PagesController

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, activeadmin

I have a rails 3 app with the ActiveAdmin gem. I have made a page.rb file that shows the list of my website's static pages that the admin could update. For specific need, I made customs views. Everything works fine except when I try to update a page. I get the error `The action 'update' could not be found for Admin::PagesController`. However, my page.rb file own an update method ! Can someone explain me what have I done wrong ?

My page.rb file:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page 'Pages' do
  content only: :index do
    render 'index'
  end

  content only: :edit do
    render partial: 'edit'
  end

  controller do
    layout 'active_admin'

    def index
      @search = Page.includes(:translations).where("page_translations.locale='fr'").metasearch(params[:search])
      @pages = @search.page params[:page]
    end

    def edit
      @page = Page.find params[:id]
    end
  end

  def update
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    @page.update_attributes(params[:page])
    redirect_to(admin_path :notice => 'Coool')
    return
  end
end
```

And the form that submit the page :

```
<%= semantic_form_for([:admin, @page], url: admin_page_path, method: :put) do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :permalink %>
    <%= f.globalize_fields_for :fr do |g| %>
      <%= g.text_field :name %>
      <%= g.text_area :content %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.globalize_fields_for :en do |g| %>
        <%= g.text_field :name %>
        <%= g.text_area :content %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button "Save" %>
  <%= link_to("Cancel", admin_pages_path) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm getting this error - ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `globalize_fields_for' for #<ActiveAdmin::Views::ActiveAdminForm:0x000055dffbc4f488>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `update` method is not inside the `controller` block. Try to move it a few lines higher.

Comment: one misplace 'end' and everything below is ignored...thanks for this